# Simple Webservice login in windows phone 8 application using C#

Tags: rest, windows-phone-8

i'm working on windows phone 8 application using C#. This application needs webservice for login authentication.
How can we call a webservice from Windows Phone 8 App. Can anyone illustrate with an example?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use [Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh761504.aspx) in order to call a `WebService` form your application.

These ones might be helpful:

[Calling Web API from a Windows Phone 8 Application](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/mobile-clients/calling-web-api-from-a-windows-phone-8-application)

[Web service on Windows Phone](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/439874/Web-service-on-Windows-Phone)